# Beginning Java SudokuSolver FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, arrays

I keep having this problem when I run my program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: samplesukodu8.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
at prac7.readSudoku(prac7.java:31)
at prac7.main(prac7.java:16)
```

This is my program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prac7 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Begin keep when submit
    // During development, you may comment out the next few lines
    // and hardcode sudokuFile to be a particular input
    if (args.length != 1) { usage(); System.exit(1); }

    String sudokuFile = args[0]; //"samplesudoku8.txt";
    System.out.println("Solving " + sudokuFile);

    int[][] sudoku = readSudoku(sudokuFile);
    simplify(sudoku);
    int[][] answer = search(sudoku);
    if (answer==null) 
      System.out.println("No answer found.");
    else 
      printSudoku( answer );
  }


  // reads a sudoku board from a text file.
  public static int[][] 
  readSudoku(String sudokuFile) throws FileNotFoundException 
  {
    File f = new File(sudokuFile);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    int[][] sudoku = new int[9][9];

    // Read in sudoku
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
      for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++)
        if (s.hasNextInt()) 
          sudoku[row][column] = s.nextInt();
    s.close();
    return sudoku;
  }

  // Simplification procedure used in assignment 7.
  public static void simplify(int[][] sudoku) {
    boolean hasMadeProgress;

    do {

      hasMadeProgress = false;

      // enumerate row
      for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (int possibility = 1; possibility <= 9; possibility++) {
          int count = 0;
          int index = -1;

          for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            if (isPossible(sudoku, row, col, possibility)) {
              count++;
              index = col;
            }
          }

          if (count == 1) {
            sudoku[row][index] = possibility;
            hasMadeProgress = true;
          }
        }
      } // end of enumerate row
      // enumerate col
      for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
        for (int possibility = 1; possibility <= 9; possibility++) {

          int count = 0;
          int index = -1;

          for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            if (isPossible(sudoku, row, col, possibility)) {
              count++;
              index = row;
            }
          }

          if (count == 1) {
            sudoku[index][col] = possibility;
            hasMadeProgress = true;
          }
        }
      } // end of enumerate col

      // end of enumerate 3x3
      for (int row = 0; row < 9; row += 3) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col += 3) {
          for (int possibility = 1; possibility <= 9; possibility++) {
            int count = 0;
            int index1 = -1, index2 = -1;

            for (int r = row; r < row + 3; r++) {
              for (int c = col; c < col + 3; c++) {
                if (isPossible(sudoku, r, c, possibility)) {
                  count++;
                  index1 = r;
                  index2 = c;
                }
              }
            }

            if (count == 1) {
              sudoku[index1][index2] = possibility;
              hasMadeProgress = true;
            }
          } // end of possibility
        } // end of col
      } // end of row
    } while (hasMadeProgress);

  }

  // This method returns true if it is possible for numToCheck to be instide
  // vals[row][column]
  public static boolean isPossible(int[][] sudoku, int row, int column,
                                   int numToCheck)
  {
    // may not be necesary
    if (sudoku[row][column] != 0)
    {
      return false;
    }

    // check same row
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      if (sudoku[row][j] == numToCheck)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // check same column
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
      if (sudoku[i][column] == numToCheck)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // check same 3x3
    int cornerRow = row / 3 * 3;
    int cornerCol = column / 3 * 3;
    for (int i = cornerRow; i < cornerRow + 3; i++)
    {
      for (int j = cornerCol; j < cornerCol + 3; j++)
      {
        if (sudoku[i][j] == numToCheck)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    return true;

  }


  /* Recursively searches for a correctly filled in version of the sudoku
     board provided as input. Returns null if there is no way of filling
     in the given sudoku board.
     Implementation note: Note that the array for the sudoku board
     is copied when a recursive call is made. This is done because the 
     recursive call may make further changes to the board when it calls
     simplify(), and it is too hard to predict where those changes will be 
     made. Instead, we just make a copy which we discard if it turns out to be
     a dead end.
  */
  public static int[][] search(int[][] sudoku) {

    if (!isSafe(sudoku)) return null;

    // look for a location to expand on.
    int expand_row = -1;
    int expand_col = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
      for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
        if (sudoku[i][j] == 0) {
          expand_row = i;
          expand_col = j;
        }
      }

    // if all filled in, then we've found an answer.
    if (expand_row==-1) return sudoku;

    // a cell needs to be filled in, try to fill it in all possible ways
    for (int fill=1; fill<=9; fill++) {
      int[][] new_sudoku = copyBoard(sudoku);      // copy the board.
      new_sudoku[expand_row][expand_col] = fill;   // fill the unknown cell
      simplify(new_sudoku);                        // simplify
      int[][] answer = search(new_sudoku);         // recursively try to solve.
      if (answer!=null) return answer;             // found answer, return.
    }

    // no answer found from this board; return null;
    return null;
  }


  // Creates a new array that is a copy of the given sudoku board.
  public static int[][] copyBoard(int[][] sudoku) {
    int[][] copy = new int[9][9];
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
      for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
        copy[i][j] = sudoku[i][j];
    return copy;
  }


  // Checks whether the give board is still safe, that is it does not 
  // have any duplicate entries in any row, column, or box.
  public static boolean isSafe(int[][] sudoku) {
    for (int fill=1; fill<9; fill++) {

      // check rows for duplicate fill values
      for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
          if (sudoku[i][j]==fill) count++;
        if (count > 1) return false;
      }

      // check columns for duplicate fill values
      for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
          if (sudoku[i][j]==fill) count++;
        if (count > 1) return false;
      }

      // check boxes for duplicate fill values
      for (int box=0; box<9; box++) {
        int count = 0;
        int startRow = 3 * (box / 3);
        int startCol = 3 * (box % 3);
        for (int i = startRow; i < startRow + 3; i++) 
          for (int j = startCol; j < startCol + 3; j++) 
            if (sudoku[i][j]==fill) count++;
        if (count > 1) return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }


  public static void printSudoku(int[][] sudoku) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++) {
        System.out.print(sudoku[row][column] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void usage() {
    System.out.println("java SodokuSolver <sudoku_input>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you think an error that says `samplesukodu8.txt (No such file or directory)` means?

Answer (score 1):

Spelling error: samplesukodu versus samplesudoku. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your `String sudokuFile` variable could be invalid. Maybe try with an `src/filename.txt` extension. Print out its value to make sure you are getting the right file directory/filename.